# Cookie not being read

Tags: javascript, cookies

I have the following functions to set and get cookies, I tested the codes on local host and it seem to be working but when I put'em up on server it does not. I can check the cookies on browsers but when I try to read them using `function getCookies()`, it does not work.

Questions:

- Am I setting cookies incorrectly?
- Why can I see cookies on browser and not pragmatically?
- Am I reading cookies incorrectly?

Code:

```
<script type="text/javascript"><!--

function getCookie(c_name)
{
var i,x,y,ARRcookies=document.cookie.split(";");
alert(ARRcookies);
for (i=0;i<ARRcookies.length;i++)
  {
  x=ARRcookies[i].substr(0,ARRcookies[i].indexOf("="));
  y=ARRcookies[i].substr(ARRcookies[i].indexOf("=")+1);
  x=x.replace(/^\s+|\s+$/g,"");
  if (x==c_name)
    {
    return unescape(y);
    }
  }
}

function setCookie(c_name,value,exdays)
{
var exdate=new Date();
exdate.setDate(exdate.getDate() + exdays);
var c_value=escape(value) + ((exdays==null) ? "" : "; expires="+exdate.toUTCString());
document.cookie=c_name + "=" + c_value;
}


function readCookie(){
  alert("here");
  var domain = checkCookie("domain");
  var tld= checkCookie("tld");
  alert(domain+" "+tld);
}

window.onload(readCookie());
// --></script>
```

**Update:** The alert inside the readCookie function shows 'undefined' which should have been the value. When I try to print ARRcookies, it shows all cookies but 'domain' and 'tld' which i've set. I can see the cookies 'domain' and 'tld' on browser's cookies list.

Comment: You're setting up the "load" handler incorrectly. It should just be `window.onload = readCookie;`

Comment: Also, it's generally a really good idea to be specific about the ways in which your code doesn't work, or works differently than you expect. Saying just that it "doesn't work" doesn't help people help you.

Comment: @Pointy What it actually it does is, alert inside the readCookie function shows 'undefined' which should have been the value. When I try to print ARRcookies, it shows all cookies but 'domain' and 'tld' which i've set. I can see the cookies 'domain' and 'tld' on browser's cookies list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code to wire up the `readCookie` function is as follows:

```js
window.onload(readCookie());
```

If you split the code into two lines, it may be easier to see:

```js
var cookie = readCookie();
window.onload(cookie);
```

So this first calls `readCookie` (as soon as the JavaScript has been loaded from the server, **before** the full `document` has been initialized).

After `readCookie` returns its result is passed to a method `window.onload`.

That leads to a few problems:

1. the `window` object doesn't have an `onload` method. It has an `onload` event that you can register for
2. you probably don't want to invoke `readCookie` when straight away, but rather you want it to be invoked by `onload`.

You can accomplish this by registering it like this (as Pointy commented):

```js
window.onload = readCookie;
```

So with this you are setting the `window.onload` event to execute your `readCookie` function. At that stage the cookies will be available.